# In iOS is it possible to change a View's coordinate system so that 0,0 is top right corner?

Tags: frame, coordinate-systems

Normally the 0,0 coordinate refers to the top left corner of a view.  Higher x coordinates are further right.  A frame / rectangle in the view has its leftmost point being its x coordinate and its rightmost point being its x coordinate plus its width.

Is it possible to reverse that, or better yet, reverse just the x axis?  Make the 0,0 be the top right.  Make the higher origins be further to the left.  AND make it so a frame / rectangle in the view has its rightmost point as its x coordinate and its leftmost point as its x coordinate plus its width.

I know I could transform this stuff myself with pure math, but I was wondering if iOS offers this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

- iOS 9 has some new flipping stuff for supporting right-to-left languages, but I don't think you can force it.
- You can flip the *drawing* of a view by setting its `transform` property to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)`, but that won't change the underlying coordinate system.
- SpriteKit has a different coordinate system than normal UIViews, but its coordinate system isn't what you want.

You may want to read [Coordinate Systems and Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html), which discusses some techniques for mapping points between different coordinate systems. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) covers mapping points using matrices, which can help you on a theoretical level.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented, but UIView has an instance variable, `_flipsHorizontalAxis`, that does exactly what it sounds like it would do. It looks like it just passes through the CALayer variable of the same name.